# Can't get the text-based game to work properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I'm currently starting out a course on programming and wrote this text-based python game. Whatever choice I put for replaying the game the code somehow displays the initial_stuff that I have made a function for:

```
play_again = input("Would you like to play again? Enter 'y' for yes or 'n' for no: ")
if play_again == "y" or "Y":
    initial_setup()
    main_loop()

elif play_again == "n" or "N":
    print("Thank you for playing")

else:
    print("Please enter either 'y' or 'n'")
```

Here the code runs but after displaying the message to replay the game if I choose to not play, it still goes to the top and runs code again. I tried debugging in pycharm but can't understand how the debugger works. I tried many things but nothing is working as of now. Please guide me how I can make this logically correct.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't write your conditions like that. It's correct in English but not in Python. `or "Y"` part is always evaluated to `True`. Except for empty string, all strings are *"truthy"*. Learn more about truth values [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

Change:

```py
if play_again == "y" or "Y":
```

To one of these:

```py
if play_again == "y" or play_again == "Y":
if play_again.lower() == "y":
if play_again in ("y", "Y"):
```